# Optimization algorithm with numbers

Tags: c++, algorithm, stdin

Given a list of numbers in increasing order and a certain sum, I'm trying to implement the optimal way of finding the sum. Using the biggest number first

```
A sample input would be:
3
1
2
5
11
```

where the first line the number of numbers we are using and the last line is the desired sum

```
the output would be:
1 x 1
2 x 5
```

which equals 11

I'm trying to interpret this https://www.classle.net/book/c-program-making-change-using-greedy-method using stdard input

Here is what i got so far

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
 int sol = 0; int array[]; int m[10];

 while (!cin.eof())
  {
   cin >> array[i];  // add inputs to an array
   i++;
  }

 x = array[0]; // number of 
 for (int i; i < x ; i++) {
  while(sol<array[x+1]){
     // try to check all multiplications of the largest number until its over the sum
     // save the multiplication number into the m[] before it goes over the sum;
     //then do the same with the second highest number and check if they can add up to sum

     }
  cout << m[//multiplication number] << "x" << array[//correct index]
  return 0;
} 

   if(sol!=array[x+1])
 {
 cout<<endl<<"Not Possible!";
 }
```

}

Finding it hard to find an efficient way of doing this in terms of trying all possible combinations starting with the biggest number? Any suggestions would be greatly helpful, since i know im clearly off

Comment: You should NOT ask any question about Assignment 3 here. Please see me after tmrw's class.

Comment: LOL.....Thatdude1 just got owned.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is a variation of the [subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), which is [NP-Hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hard).

An NP-Hard problem is a problem that (among other things) - there is no known polynomial solution for it, thus the greedy approach of "getting the highest first" fails for it.

However, for this NP-Hard problem, there is a pseudo-polynomial solution using dynamic programming. The problem where you can chose each number more then once is called the con change problem.

[This page](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Coin_Change) contains explanation and possible solutions for the problem.